# Ayuda con expresión Regular para vb.net

Tags: vb.net, regex

Voy directo al grano

Tengo la siguiente String (en realidad son más datos, pero solo he cogido un fragmento)

> {"readDate":"2017-11-09T00:00:00","diffPrevIndexLastHour":706369.0,"diffPrevWd1Vol":23076.0,"diffPrevWd2Vol":235301.0,"diffPrevWd3Vol":78883.0,"diffPrevWd4Vol":151556.0,"diffPrevWd5Vol":214025.0,"diffPrevWd6Vol":0.0,"diffPrevWd7Vol":3528.0},{"readDate":"2017-11-10T00:00:00","diffPrevIndexLastHour":708118.0,"diffPrevWd1Vol":22849.0,"diffPrevWd2Vol":216209.0,"diffPrevWd3Vol":122530.0,"diffPrevWd4Vol":180623.0,"diffPrevWd5Vol":162584.0,"diffPrevWd6Vol":0.0,"diffPrevWd7Vol":3323.0},{"readDate":"2017-11-11T00:00:00","diffPrevIndexLastHour":703674.0,"diffPrevWd1Vol":2724.0,"diffPrevWd2Vol":353987.0,"diffPrevWd3Vol":17605.0,"diffPrevWd4Vol":219259.0,"diffPrevWd5Vol":87787.0,"diffPrevWd6Vol":0.0,"diffPrevWd7Vol":22312.0}

Como podéis observar este fragmento contiene los datos de 3 días, analizo uno para una mejor comprensión:

> {"readDate":"2017-11-09T00:00:00","diffPrevIndexLastHour":706369.0,"diffPrevWd1Vol":23076.0,"diffPrevWd2Vol":235301.0,"diffPrevWd3Vol":78883.0,"diffPrevWd4Vol":151556.0,"diffPrevWd5Vol":214025.0,"diffPrevWd6Vol":0.0,"diffPrevWd7Vol":3528.0}

Tenemos un "ReadDate" que nos da el día que se toma la medición y después 8 datos numéricos. Cada día medido está separado por llaves.

En este caso sería

> fecha= 2017-11-09
>
> dato1=706369.0
>
> dato2=23076.0
>
> dato3=235301.0
>
> dato4=78883.0
>
> dato5=151556.0
>
> dato6=214025.0
>
> dato7=0.0
>
> dato8=3528.0

El objetivo sería obtener la fecha y los 8 datos numéricos de una cadena como la mencionada al principio (aunque mucho más larga).

En realidad las expresiones regulares son mi criptonita y he sido incapaz de sacar algo en claro. Se me ocurre que podría tener dos soluciones:

1º una expresión regular que cogiera las fechas y otra que cogiera los números, de tal manera que los 8 primeros números de la segunda cadena corresponden a la primera fecha

2ºuna expresión regular que cogiera todos los datos mencionados sabiendo que el primer dato que encontremos será la fecha y los 8 siguientes los datos.

Mi problema es con la expresión regular, el cómo implementarlo sería algo así.

```
Dim pattern As String = "endemoniadaExpresionRegular"
Dim result() As String = Regex.Split(StringConLosDatos, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

De todos modos, si hubiera alguna forma de hacerlo sin expresiones regulares sería mucho más feliz, pero creo que no es el caso jeje.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te estás complicando muchisimo la vida. Eso es un simple JSON, y con  [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) puedes deserializarlo sin problemas y de manera sencilla

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, no asumir que la solución es con regex (ya que no es así), sacarle la etiqueta, y vas a tener mejores respuestas... Además, ¿Puede ser que te hayas olvidado unos corchetes al inicio y final del string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la ayuda de [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), deserializar esos datos es muy sencillo.

Primero, debes importar Json.Net en tu proyecto, bien buscándolo en el administrador de paquetes NuGet, o ejecutando este comando en la consola de Nuget:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.2
```

Luego, se crea la clase que coincide con tu json. La manera mas sencilla es copiar unos datos de ejemplo, y usar en visual studio *Editar*/*Pegado Especial*/*Pegar JSON como clases*. Esto en tu caso, genera una clase como esta:

```
Public Class Datos
    Public Property readDate As String
    Public Property diffPrevIndexLastHour As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd1Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd2Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd3Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd4Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd5Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd6Vol As Single
    Public Property diffPrevWd7Vol As Single
End Class
```

Por último, deserializar es cosa de una línea prácticamente:

```
Dim input As String = "[{'readDate':'2017 - 11 - 09T00: 00:00','diffPrevIndexLastHour':706369.0,'diffPrevWd1Vol':23076.0,'diffPrevWd2Vol':235301.0,'diffPrevWd3Vol':78883.0,'diffPrevWd4Vol':151556.0,'diffPrevWd5Vol':214025.0,'diffPrevWd6Vol':0.0,'diffPrevWd7Vol':3528.0},{'readDate':'2017 - 11 - 09T00: 00:00','diffPrevIndexLastHour':706369.0,'diffPrevWd1Vol':23076.0,'diffPrevWd2Vol':235301.0,'diffPrevWd3Vol':78883.0,'diffPrevWd4Vol':151556.0,'diffPrevWd5Vol':214025.0,'diffPrevWd6Vol':0.0,'diffPrevWd7Vol':3528.0}]"
Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Datos))(input)
```

He usado un array con dos datos como ejemplo. Despues de la ejecución, en `data` tienes una lista de objetos `Datos` en la que puedes acceder a sus propiedades directamente.

Comment: @CharlieMR Perdona que haya tardado en contestar. Simplemente, `data(i).readDate` por ejemplo debería servirte